# From JSON file to Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, json, mongodb, numpy

I have a MongoDB collection, which, when imported to Python via PyMongo, is a dictionnary in Python.
I am looking to transform it into a Numpy Array.

For instance, if the JSON file looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57065024c3d1132426c4dd53"),

    "B" : {
        "BA" : 14,
        "BB" : 23,
        "BC" : 32,
        "BD" : 41
    "A" : 50,
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57065024c3d1132426c4dd53"),
    "A" : 1
    "B" : {
        "BA" : 1,
        "BB" : 2,
        "BC" : 3,
        "BD" : 4
```

}

I'd like to get in return this 5*2 Numpy Array :
    np.array([[50,14,23,32,41],
    [1,1,2,3,4]])
In that case, the first column corresponds to "A", the second one to "BA", the third one to "BB", etc.
Notice that keys are not always sorted in the same order.

My code, which does not work at all (and does not do what I want yet) looks like this :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
uri = "mongodb://localhost/test"
client = MongoClient(uri)
db=client.recodb
collection=db.recos

list1=list(collection.find())
array2=np.vstack([[product[key] for key in product.keys()] for product in list1])
```

Comment: I don't know MongoDB, but that isn't a valid JSON object. Is it supposed to be a list of dictionaries? Also, `ObjectId("57065024c3d1132426c4dd53")` isn't a valid JSON item: it should be serialised as some kind of string, eg `"ObjectId(\"57065024c3d1132426c4dd53\")"`.

Comment: That is how the file looks in RoboMongo, which I use to vizualize this collection.

Comment: Then, 'list1' is a list of dictionnary. About the slashes, I am not sure, but since I do not use in the end, it does not really matter.

Comment: MongoDB stores data in BSON format, not plain json. That is why those ObjectIds are there. Shouldn't matter for this question though.

Answer (score 1):

The [flatdict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flatdict) module can sometimes be useful when working with mongodb data structures. It will handle flattening the nested dictionary structure for you:

```
columns = []
for d in data:
    flat = flatdict.FlatDict(d)
    del flat['_id']
    columns.append([item[1] for item in sorted(flat.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])])
np.vstack(columns)
```

Of course this can be solved without flatdict too.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to achieve this without using a loop on 'data'? 'data' I am actually going to use cointains 14000 elements.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about not looping on 'data'. One thing that you could do to increase the speed (if it is needed) is to create the numpy array as the first thing you do and then add the elements from mongodb into that array. I would try the solution as is first though, to make sure that I was optimizing prematurely.

Comment: What I mean by looping on data is : is there a way to solve the problem without any loop : `for d in data`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've successfully loaded that JSON into Python, here's one way to create the Numpy array you want. My code has a minimal definition of `ObjectId` so that it won't raise a NameError on `ObjectId` entries.

```
sorted(d["B"].items())]
```

produces a list of (key, value) tuples from the contents of a "B" dictionary, sorted by key. We then extract just the values from those tuples into a list, and append that list to a list containing the value from the "A" item.

```
import numpy as np

class ObjectId(object):
    def __init__(self, objectid):
        self.objectid = objectid

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ObjectId("{}")'.format(self.objectid)

data = [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57065024c3d1132426c4dd53"),
        "B" : {
            "BA" : 14,
            "BB" : 23,
            "BC" : 32,
            "BD" : 41
        },
        "A" : 50
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57065024c3d1132426c4dd53"),
        "A" : 1,
        "B" : {
            "BA" : 1,
            "BB" : 2,
            "BC" : 3,
            "BD" : 4
        }
    }
]

array2 = np.array([[d["A"]] + [v for _, v in sorted(d["B"].items())] for d in data])
print(array2)
```

**output**

```
[[50 14 23 32 41]
 [ 1  1  2  3  4]]
```